# MsTest : Actual value increases everytime test method runs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, mstest

Here is my test class

```
[TestClass]
public class FooServiceTest
{
    private IYourRepository _yourRepository;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _yourRepository = new Mock<YourRepository>().Object;

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPushableEntries_gets_all_pushable_entries()
    {
        var yourObjectList = new List<YourObject>
        {
            new WaitingQueue
            {                   
                ProfileId = 26,
                IsDeleted = false,
                Pushable = true
            },
            new WaitingQueue
            {                    
                ProfileId = 27,
                IsDeleted = false,
                Pushable = true
            },
            new WaitingQueue
            {                   
                ProfileId = 28,
                IsDeleted = false,
                Pushable = false
            }

        };

        foreach (var yourObject in yourObjectList)
        {
            _yourRepository.Create(yourObject);
        }

        var pushableEntries = _yourRepository.GetList(x => x.Pushable);
        pushableEntries.Count.ShouldEqual(2);
        pushableEntries.ShouldNotBeNull();
        pushableEntries.ShouldBe<IReadOnlyCollection<WaitingQueue>>();

    }

}
```

Here is the `ShouldEqual` method

```
public static T ShouldEqual<T>(this T actual, object expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    return actual;
}
```

and here is the `GetList` method

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> @where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] nav)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return GetFiltered(dbContext, nav).Where(where).ToList();
    }
}
```

Every time I run `GetPushableQueues_gets_all_pushable_entries()` method

The actual value is increased by 2.

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2>. Actual:<2>. //first run
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2>. Actual:<4>. //second run
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2>. Actual:<6>. //third run
```

This problem persists even if I clean the test project and rebuild it.
Any idea why this is happening and what am I missing?

Note: There are other test methods that use `_yourRepository` and call `Create` method to create an entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually using some kind of repository there.
You don't mock it.
_yourRepository = new Mock< YourRepository >().Object;

Should be 
_yourRepository = new Mock< IYourRepository >().Object;

And all the methods you use from the IYourRepository interface should be mocked/set up as well.

Comment: Hmm I should mock all the methods of the 'IYourRepository' too? And mocking the class that implements IYourRepository doesn't work?

Comment: No, mocking the class does not work. You don't need to mock them all, only those which you use in the particular test.

Comment: You mean mock particular methods? I am new to this testing thing. The way my application is setup is there is generic repository which is inherited by ISomeRepository and ISomeService inherits and extends ISomeRepository. I want to test methods in SomeService class. So according to what you said I should only mock the methods I need from ISomeRepository and then use to test method that I need from SomeService?

Comment: And please pay attention to the line "using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())". When there is a dbcontext, you are not mocking anything. It connects to the real database (unless you have configured the in memory one).

Comment: Yes, only setup the "_repository.GetList" method. That should be enough.

Comment: Hmm, I was also thinking about that. I might come into problem while testing DbContext. What do you suggest could be good way to make it more testable?

Comment: The only way I know to test the DBContext is to use in Memory database. Details about that could be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory.
And if you just need to test the business logic mocking the repository is the best way.